# Controlling minted cache filenames (.pygtex)

Tags: minted

I have two nearly-identical documents with slightly different settings (one with 11pt font, and the other with 10pt), say `book10.tex` and `book11.tex`. They import a code snippet with minted using `\inputminted`.

I'm trying to reuse the minted cache from the first book to the others, unfortunately, it seems that the cache filenames are different. After compiling both books with xelatex:

```
xelatex --shell-escape book10.tex && xelatex --shell-escape book11.tex
```

I seem to have two .pygtex files, with the first part of the hash being identical, but the second part is different:

```
$ ls
FCA5498F9EAF9E235804E47AA988230D31F590DAF3C4999269D16864F0C9105B.pygtex
FCA5498F9EAF9E235804E47AA988230D796938E665113EC976EFD1EDB1C66E95.pygtex
...
```

Their contents are identical, but the file names are different.

According to a footnote in the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf), "cache files are named using an MD5 hash of highlighting settings and highlighted
text". I can understand the "highlighted text" part, but what are the highlighting settings, and why do they hash differently?

My MWE is:

**hello.hs**

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello world!
```

**book10.tex** and **book11.tex (simplified)**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cachedir=_mycache]{minted}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{octave}{hello.hs}

\end{document}
```

**Question**: Can I override the produced filenames? I want to keep the hash of the contents, ignoring the settings hash.

N.B. The solution using `\finalizecache` doesn't work for my situation, because some files use a macro that imports snippets in a different language instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! I took a closer look at the [`minted.sty`](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.sty) file, and noticed that the `jobname` was considered as a part of the hash. So I now specify the same `-jobname` value to xelatex and it seemed to work!

I asked this question on the `minted` github, and the [answer](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/252#issuecomment-586120301) I got suggests doing something similar, specifying `\minted@jobname` in the .tex file directly.

If that helps, I [summarized the steps](https://hmemcpy.com/2020/02/speeding-up-your-latex-builds-by-reusing-minted-caches/) on my blog.